# The most efficient way to count user RSVPs by location?

Tags: mysql, count

I have a user table, an events table (containing a city location), and an RSVP table (which users went to which event). I'd like to analyse which users went to the most events in a particular city.

I think I need a new table called user_location_counts in which I have the following columns: user, location and count, where count is the count of the RSVPs of a given user in a given city. Then, I only need a query like:

```
SELECT user FROM user_location_counts WHERE city = 'XYZ' ORDER BY count DESC.
```

What is the most efficient way to build this table? Is there a better way to do it? I have about 3M users and 10M RSVP items meaning efficiency is very important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create the table with a query like:

```
create table User_Location_Counts as
    select r.userId, e.city, count(*) as cnt
    from rsvp r join
         events e
         on e.eventId = r.eventId
    group by r.userId, e.city;
```

If you need to keep the table up-to-date as new data is added, then you might need triggers.  Alternatively, you would need to rebuild the table periodically, if you can live with a lag.

Comment: Thanks! Wouldn't an inner join allow you to remove the group by? Also isn't count(1) quicker than count (*)? I've been running the query for 10 mins and it hasn't resolved yet...

Comment: @DavidBailey . . . An inner join has nothing to do with a group by.  You want the counts per city.  As for whether `count(*)` or `count(1)` are faster, I suggest that you look at the copious number of questions on that topic (and, in the execution phase, they should be have the same performance).

Comment: Thanks Gordon.I'll also look into triggers. I'd already looked into count and my conclusion and experimentation suggested that count(1) was quicker. Cheers!